# android -best way to communicate between activity and background service

Tags: android, ipc

I'm trying to build a small MusicPlayer for learning purposes, and I'm stuck at a point on how to make communication between a background process and the activity.  I've haven't seen anyone else's code but in my(almost amateur design) the activity and the service must be updating each other every second since the activity's control should be reflected in the services controls(like if the service had a GUI in android's notification bar) and the music playing should update the Activity's seekbar etc.

What would be the best way to implement the service, so that it can run independent but in sync with the activity?

Answer (score 0):

I followed these instructions:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services

> A bound service is an implementation of the Service class that allows other applications to bind to it and interact with it. To provide binding for a service, you must implement the onBind() callback method. This method returns an IBinder object that defines the programming interface that clients can use to interact with the service.

Basically you implement your service and your activity as you have done and then when the activity resumes it can bind the service so that they can communicate.

In that same page you can find some code of how is it done in java and kotlin.

Comment: can you bind the service with more than one activity? And don't bound service end when you destroy the app?

Comment: In my case I had only to bound the service that controlled the hardware accelerators to one activity but I'm pretty sure you can bind it to many activities, I don't see why not. You could leave the activity  which got destroyed and return to it and it got binded again. And the service continues running independent of the activity, I'm sure about this because I had to, but it must be a foreground service and it can be killed by the system at any time (alarms are a good way to wake it up in case this happens)

Comment: all activities are just classes that run in a single process,right? Yet, why is the page you linked in the docs saying that "A bound service is the server in a client-server interface. It allows components (such as activities) to bind to the service, send requests, receive responses, and perform **interprocess communication (IPC)**"?

Comment: I suppose it's because the service would act as the server in that scenario and the activity as the client (asking for data or actions and receiving the feedback from the service). There were other ways of communication but what you describe can be done with a bounded service. Try it

Comment: it does seem to fit the need, except for one thing, every 10 ms the service would have to send data to the activity, I don't know while technically how much overhead is this but it seems it'd be very useful if the service and activity shared some variables, given that they both run in a thread, this should be possible but IDK. Do you know any way?

Comment: actually thinking about it more, there's even more overhead since the playqueue should be known to the service since the activity might be destroyed at any point, and to restore state the service should also have to access the database

Comment: Every 10ms? Well, I'm not sure in that case, I had to sync every second

Comment: um... the seekbar could be laggy if you'd update it every second

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209218/discussion-between-jeprubio-and-mathmaniage).